# How to remove red line under words after click in my off element?

Tags: jquery, html

my English language is not good.sorry

How to reload text area after click "off" element (After clicking on the "On") for remove red line under words.

thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('textarea').focus();

  $(".on").click(function() {
    $('textarea').attr('spellcheck','true');
    $('textarea').focus();
  });

  $(".off").click(function() {
    $('textarea').attr('spellcheck','false');
    $('textarea').focus();
  });

});
```

```css
.on {
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  padding:5px;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer
}
.off {
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  padding:5px;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea>sadasarwedfhtfuf</textarea><br>

<a class="on">Red Line On</a>
<a class="off">Red Line Off</a>
```

Comment: Are you trying to have an automatic spellchecker? Like as in using a 3rd party tool to do this, or what are you basing the validation on?

Comment: I think the question is about how to toggle the browser's native spell checking on an element based on a button click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you enable the spellchecker, it puts the red line, and once you disable the spellchecker, it disables it but it doesn't get rid of the already-placed red line. If you just use `html()`, you can essentially replace the text with the new settings.

[Explanation of how html() works with and without arguments](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

**EDIT:**
I've changed it to val() instead so that it would update with whatever text the textarea contains. I also created a placeholder to store the initial value and then changed the value to "" to essentially clear it.

[Explanation of how val() works with and without arguments](https://api.jquery.com/val/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var text = $('textarea');

  text.focus();

  $(".on").click(function() {
    text.attr('spellcheck',true);
    text.focus();
  });

  $(".off").click(function() {
    let value = text.val()
    text.val("");
    text.attr('spellcheck',false);
    text.val(value); // ***
    text.focus();
  });

});
```

```css
.on {
  background-color:green;
  color:white;
  padding:5px;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.off {
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  padding:5px;
  margin:10px;
  float:left;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea>sadasarwedfhtfuf</textarea><br>

<a class="on">Red Line On</a>
<a class="off">Red Line Off</a>
```

Comment: thanks, but not work after typing words in textarea